# ListAdapter.submitList() ignores new list order

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If I submit one list and then submit another which for example 90% has the same items but items is quite in different order then RecyclerView doesn't respect really new list order, just ignores, and just changes items partly (delete old items which isn't new list and some other think)

Why is that? Is there some flag/option to tell Adapter of RecyclerView do not ignore the list order

For now the only solution I see is always call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `submitList`:

```
adapter.submitList(it.data) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```